# Replace all instances of a specific import via jscodeshift

Tags: javascript, jscodeshift, codemod

okay so I have code that looks like this:

```js
import { wait } from "@testing-library/react";

describe("MyTest", () => {
  it("should wait", async () => {
    await wait(() => {
      console.log("Done");
    });
  });
});
```

I want to change that import member `wait` to be `waitFor`. I'm able to change it in the AST like so:

```js
    source
      .find(j.ImportDeclaration)
      .filter((path) => path.node.source.value === "@testing-library/react")
      .find(j.ImportSpecifier)
      .filter((path) => path.node.imported.name === "wait")
      .replaceWith(j.importSpecifier(j.identifier("waitFor")))
      .toSource()
```

However, the outputed code will look as follows:

```js
import { waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";

describe("MyTest", () => {
  it("should wait", async () => {
    await wait(() => {
      console.log("Done");
    });
  });
});
```

I'm looking for a way to change all subsequent usages of that import to match the new name

Is this possible with jscodeshift?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by visiting all the `CallExpression` nodes, filtering for those with the name you're targeting ("wait") and replacing them with new nodes.

To find the relevant nodes you can either loop through the collection returned by jscodeshift's `find()` method and add your logic there, or you can give `find()` a second argument. This should be a predicate used for filtering:

```
const isWaitExpression = (node) =>
    node.callee && node.callee.name === "wait";

// I've used "root" where you used "source"
root
    .find(j.CallExpression, isWaitExpression)
```

Then you can replace those nodes with `replaceWith()`:

```
const replaceExpression = (path, j) =>
    j.callExpression(j.identifier("waitFor"), path.node.arguments);

root
   .find(j.CallExpression, isWaitExpression)
   .replaceWith((path) => replaceExpression(path, j));
```

It can look a bit confusing, but to create a `CallExpression` node, you call the `callExpression()` method from the api. Note the camel-casing there.

All together, a transformer that renames "wait" from RTL to "waitFor" — both the named import declaration and every instance where it's called in the file — can be done like this:

```
const isWaitExpression = (node) => node.callee && node.callee.name === "wait";

const replaceExpression = (path, j) =>
  j.callExpression(j.identifier("waitFor"), path.node.arguments);

export default function transformer(file, api) {
  const j = api.jscodeshift;
  const root = j(file.source);

  root
    .find(j.ImportDeclaration)
    .filter((path) => path.node.source.value === "@testing-library/react")
    .find(j.ImportSpecifier)
    .filter((path) => path.node.imported.name === "wait")
    .replaceWith(j.importSpecifier(j.identifier("waitFor")));

  root
    .find(j.CallExpression, isWaitExpression)
    .replaceWith((path) => replaceExpression(path, j));

  return root.toSource();
}
```

And here's a [link to it on AST explorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/3deb0aefd71a194b77db3e9cbb4a88cb/b5660f9077caa07795b6dbf3971d89daaae7a62c)